# Automatically convert data in a column into hyperlinks?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet with a list of names in column A and list of id's in column B.
Is there a way create a single formula, which will convert data in column A into hyperlinks using column A data as title (visible text) and column B data as hyperlink address?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please post a sample of what you are trying to achieve ? and the ways you've tried.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cGZdYj7lGozxq35ty_uRsc3_nldNxcrUFSPe_wI4Pbo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

U can create 3rd column C using data of column A & B.
click on the new column C & in the "fx area" put

```
=HYPERLINK(<click on column B >, <click on column A>)
```

which will look like

```
=HYPERLINK(B:B,A:A)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there way make this more automatic, so I don't have to add such formula in each row?

Comment: try =ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,HYPERLINK(B2:B,A2:A))) in cell C2

Comment: That's pretty good! Thanks. Please post it as an answer. Even though it's not exactly as I wanted, it's certainly is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: You can just click on the whole column (say C) and type Hyperlink() command in the "fx" text area.  This way you don't need to put add formula in each row, this applies to all rows of a particular column.